# Is enmimaquinafunciona.com allowed to provide ServerFault questions in Spanish?

Tags: support

I just spotted the site http://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/ and it seems to contain only translations of posts from Server Fault and other SE communities like Ask Ubuntu to Spanish.

Are they allowed to do this or should Stack Exchange take action to stop them?

Comment: Same they do for http://askubuntu.com

Comment: @Videonauth Yeah, sorry, I missed that at first. I thought they copy mainly Server Fault stuff because they even state that on their front page.

Comment: As it seems to affect more sites than only Server Fault, should this question maybe better be migrated to the *big* Meta?

Comment: I know it only because i found an Q&A of mine today on their site http://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/40074/como-puedo-rebajar-gedit-a-una-anterior-3104-la-version-en-ubuntu-1604-lts

Answer (score 6):

Please see there; [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What do I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do)

SE rarelly bring into justice content scrapper from comments I seen in the past as often those sites close by themself over time.

So the contact us is your answer, to be sure meta staff know that site.